# How to add a variable in php comming from another file

Tags: php

Maybe I'm not doing the right question, or I'm not expressing myself very clear or accurately...

The problem is next:

**file1.php**

```
......
require_once "locales/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
......
```

**locales/en.php**

```
<?php
$lang = array(
"text1" => "Access",
        );
?>
```

**file2.php**

```
......
include ('file1.php');
......
// User is not logged in, display one of the forms
private function form($error,$formname) {
    // Throttle failed attempts
    if($formname == 'signin' && $error != 0)
        sleep(1);

    // Show a sign up or sign in link in the navigation
    if($formname == 'signin')
        $link = '<p><a href="?form=signup">Create new account</a></p>';
    else
        $link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">Access</a></p>';

......
```

So I need to change the "Access" word to the variable that inserts the word from the en.php file, but after trying many syntaxes I couldn't succeed, what's the way to do it?

**Things I've tried:**

```
$link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">'.$lang['text1'].'</a></p>';


$link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">'.$lang["text1"].'</a></p>';


$link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">'.$lang[text1].'</a></p>';
```

and some more...

**[SOLUTION]**
I finally found how to solve this:

At file2.php, after the include line I recover the variable this way:

```
$_POST['text1'] = $lang['text1'];
```

and then, inside the function I recover it like this:

```
// User is not logged in, display one of the forms
    private function form($error,$formname) {
        // Throttle failed attempts
        if($formname == 'signin' && $error != 0)
            sleep(1);

    // Show a sign up or sign in link in the navigation
    if($formname == 'signin')
        $link = '<p><a href="?form=signup">Create new account</a></p>';
    else
        $link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">" .$_POST['text1']. "</a></p>';
```

Comment: Please put `print_r($lang);` in `file2.php` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: it shows `Array ([text1] => Access)`

Comment: So `$lang['text1']` will give you the value. Please add in your question the code that **display** this value.

Comment: That should work as is. We cannot find the problem in the code as you're showing it. But also: consider using an established i18n system like gettext.

Comment: @A.L Either I don't get what you're asking for or you didn't see the code at the question

Comment: considering provided information,  $lang['text1'] should work. the problem should be somewhere outside

Comment: `$link` is never shown, did you forgot `echo $link;`?

Comment: @A.L no, all $link are shown by default, the one containing the word "Access" is shown with no problem, the ones containing the variable are not shown.

Comment: You didn't include the code that show `$link` in your question, we can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: @A.L  Ok, I edited the question and added some more where it says: Show a sign up or sign... I don't know if that is what you were asking for...

Comment: @A.L I better added the whole function

Comment: The problem is exactly that you're using a function. Read the duplicated linked at the top of your question.

Comment: @deceze Yes, I realize that the problem comes from that, I'm reading the question duplicated linked, but it is hard to get it...

Comment: this is wrong `$link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">" .$_POST['text1']. "</a></p>';` should be `$link = '<p><a href="'.$this->clean_uri().'">' .$_POST['text1']. '</a></p>';` misplaced double quotes.